# Complicated (for me) database query in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

1. One record in our database tracks the frequency that person A gives gifts to person B.
2. A different record in our database tracks the frequency that person B gives gifts to person A.
3. Another record tracks the frequency that person A gives something to person C.
4. Since person C has never given anything to person A there is no record for that.
5. Multiply that pattern by 50 people That A has giving and/or receiving relationships with.

users table has 'id' and 'name'

gifts table has 'giver_id' and 'receiver_id'

profile_pictures has 'user_id' and 'picture_url'

User model:

```
has_one :profile_picture
has_many :gifts
```

ProfilePicture:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Gift model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I am having trouble pulling the array from the database once. The array needs to be alphabetized by name. I began with:

```
parties = Gift.where("giver_id = ? || receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

And tried to work backwards. I tried getting all the users with profile pictures included and attempted to map them to the Gifts array. I couldn't make that work.

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:
Current Result on test data:

```
Clower, Steve
Gallipert, Jay   
Gallipert, Erin
Gallipert, Jay   
Gallipert, Jay
Gallipert, Linda   
Gallipert, Jay
Gallipert, Erin   
Gallipert, Jay
Garrent, Kara   
Gallipert, Jay
Atkal, Andrew   
Gallipert, Jay
Dystrom, Paul   
Gallipert, Jay
Clower, Steve   
Gallipert, Linda
Gallipert, Jay   
Garrent, Kara
Gallipert, Jay
```

What I need:

```
Atkal, Andrew
Clower, Steve 
Dystrom, Paul   
Gallipert, Erin   
Gallipert, Jay  
Gallipert, Linda   
Garrent, Kara
```

I'm wondering if the only way to do this is to

1. dump all the names into one array
2. sort the array in Ruby
3. re-query the database with the sorted array to get the profile picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Gift
  belongs_to :giver, :foreign_key => "giver_id", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, :foreign_key => "receiver_id", :class_name => "User"
end

gifts = Gift.where("giver_id = :id OR receiver_id = :id",:id => current_user.id).includes(:giver => :profile_picture).order('users.name').includes(:receiver => :profile_picture)
# gifts sorted by giver name
# users and profile picture are included in gifts array
```

Example of usage:

```
gifts.each do |gift|
  gift.giver.name # giver name
  gift.giver.profile_picture.picture_url # giver picture url
  gift.receiver.name # receiver name
  gift.receiver.profile_picture.picture_url # receiver picture url
end
```

UPDATE:

for test data try this code:

```
gifts = Gift.select('giver_id,receiver_id').uniq.includes(:giver => :profile_picture,:receiver => :profile_picture)
gifts.sort!{|x,y| "#{x.giver.name} #{x.receiver.name}" <=> "#{y.giver.name} #{y.receiver.name}"}
gifts.each{|g| puts "#{g.giver.name}, #{g.receiver.name}"}
```

Output is:

```
Atkal, Andrew
Clower, Steve
Dystrom, Paul
Gallipert, Erin
Gallipert, Jay
Gallipert, Linda
Garrent, Kara
```

Not very ellegant, but pretty fast. Maybe somebody help us to sort gifts by SQL.

Comment: Hi, nyaa... Thanks! +1 this is MUCH closer than I ever got. However, I need the whole list alphabetized, not just the giver or receiver side. e.g. jay(receiver), nyaa(giver), ralph(giver). if we got both sides into one array that was alphabetized that would work.

Comment: @Jay, if one gift: jay(giver), nyaa(receiver) and second gift: nyaa(giver), jay(receiver). How it need to be alphabetized? :)